# How to set a variable with a modulo result in windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, module, set

I'm trying to set a variable with the results of a *modulo*, but seems my syntax isn't acceptable by *Windows 7 batch*.

**Demonstration code:**

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do (
    echo.i %%i
    set /a "mod=%%i %% 3"
    echo.mod %mod%
)
```

And **output is wrong**, namely, the modulo is not changing with each iteration of the *for loop*:

```
    d:\>tmp
    i 1
    mod 2
    i 2
    mod 2
    i 3
    mod 2
    i 4
    mod 2
    i 5
    mod 2
    i 6
    mod 2
    i 7
    mod 2
    i 8
    mod 2
    d:\>
```

Comment: You need to use delayedexpansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do (
    echo.i %%i
    set /a "mod=%%i %% 3"
    echo.mod !mod!
)
```

See `Setlocal /?` for details.

Comment: Indeed Matt, these changes did the trick. Thanks for the fast reply and for the _Setlocal_ pointer.